# How to verify that one ML-classifier is better then the other using the same train and test data set without cross-validation?

Tags: statistical-significance, model-evaluation, precision-recall, confusion-matrix, f1

I have compared 5 methods (ML classifiers) on the same data set. These methods are 5 different types of neural networks. Each is trained on the training set and evaluated with precision, recall and f1-score on a test set.

Fourtanetly, there is one model that have some descent better precision, recall and f1-score which also makes logical sense because of the architecture of the model. Additionally, I want to attribute these improvements to the method / model architecture and exclude any statistical chance.

I can not use any cross-validation methods, since my data set is manually divided to avoid any relation between groups of examples of each class. **So are there any statistical methods or approaches that strength my assumption that the better performance is contributed by the special architecture of the model?**

Thanks in advance!